# Error while installing SharePoint Server 2013 after installing SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation

I am new to the SharePoint platform. I am trying to set up my development machine.  I want to install SharePoint 2013. My OS is Windows server 2008 R2, DB is SQL Server 2008 R2. After installing SharePoint Foundation 2013 on my pc, I am getting an error when try to install SharePoint Server 2013.

[image]

How do I resolve this error? If you have any questions, please ask. Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

Comment: Please avoid showing product keys in the future.

Comment: After a lot of googling I have  learn that share point is a nothing but a website so it’s need aps.net  and sharepoint foundation is the core framework with out framework how to install sharepoint server.So I need to install foundation first then server if I am not wrong or miss guide.what to do now?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove SharePoint Foundation 2013 and than install SharePoint Server 2013.. You cannot install SharePoint Server on the top of SharePoint Foundation..

I have faced this problem.. :)

Reference:

[SharePoint 2013: Migrate from SharePoint Foundation 2013 to SharePoint Server 2013](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16033.sharepoint-2013-migrate-from-sharepoint-foundation-2013-to-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx)

Comment: Arsalan Adam Khatri thanks for reply, after a lot of googling I have  learn that share point is a nothing but a website so it’s need aps.net  and sharepoint foundation is the core framework with out framework how to install sharepoint server.So I need to install foundation first then server if I am not wrong or miss guide.what to do now?

Comment: No this isn't the case, SharePoint Foundation is just a free (limited) version of SharePoint. If you want SharePoint Server license (full version) you just need to install SharePoint Server setup files and it will include the needed framework. For now you have to remove SharePoint Foundation 2013 and then install SharePoint Server 2013. You can download the trial version of SharePoint 2013 and install it with your key. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=403832